# How do I randomize my program's Window Title?

Tags: c++

I am trying to make my program have a different window title each time it get's compiled.

```
void rndmTitle() {
    int num;
    int length = 15;

    std::string characters = "abcdefghi9182345jklmnopqrstuv211935960473wxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890";
    for (int j = 0; j < length; j++)
    {
        num = rand() % 80 + 1;
    }
    SetConsoleTitle(characters[val.num]);
}
```

I got that code from a password generator I had made a while ago.
However it doesn't work like I thought it would.

It's supposed to take random letters/numbers from those 81 characters in "string characters" and then set it as window title.

But if I try to set the console title, it'll just tell me that the argument of type "char" is incompatible with parameter of type "LPCSTR".

Comment: So your question is really "how can I convert a char / `std::string` to `LPCSTR`"?

Comment: Well, no. My question is how to randomize my program's window title. The code above was just a example of what i've tried. It's incorrect tho. Im just trying to figure out how I'd do this.

Comment: No, @Tas is right. Given a problem, you must break it down into sub-problems, and you've yet to do that. Your goal is randomised window titles, but that's not really the problem you're having at this moment. Your problem is found in a small part of _implementing_ the _solution_ to that goal. For example, you already solved the randomisation part. This might sound like nitpicking, but it's actually an absolutely crucial part of problem-solving, and it's also necessary for questions here. :)

Comment: Explain what title you want. Is it a string of one character that you want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your title creation should be something like:

```
void rndmTitle(){
    constexpr int length = 15;
    const auto characters = TEXT("abcdefghi9182345jklmnopqrstuv211935960473wxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890");
    TCHAR title[length + 1]{};

    for (int j = 0; j != length; j++)
    {
        title[j] += characters[rand() % 80];
    }

    SetConsoleTitle(title);
}
```

Comment: Except you can't pass a std::string directly to SetConsoleTitle.

Comment: You mean `SetConsoleTitle(title.c_str());` which is ultimately the answer to his compilation issue.

Comment: `.c_str()` added.

Comment: Alright. I've gotten it to work. Forgot to define a length. If I restart the program or re-compile it, it keeps the same title. It does not change at all. @Jarod42

Comment: Changed to use TCHAR and get rid of UNICODE issue between `string`/`wstring`.

Comment: Have you **seed** `rand` once in main (using time or similar)?

Comment: Damn. I forgot about that. Thank you. It works just perfect now.
Also, sorry for my poor question / explanations.

Answer (score 0):

This also works

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include <Windows.h>

using namespace std;

std::string gen_string(const int length)
{
    std::string GeneratedString;
    static const char Alphabet[] = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"; 
    srand((unsigned)time(NULL) * 5);
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) 
        GeneratedString += Alphabet[rand() % (sizeof(Alphabet) - 1)];
    return GeneratedString;
}

int main()
{
    SetConsoleTitleA(gen_string(25).c_str());
}
```

credits to [this dude](https://github.com/ALEHACKsp/c-gen-string/blob/main/console_gen.cpp)